# Decomposition of the space according to the Ergodic Theorem

Tags: ergodic-theory, limits-and-convergence

Given a space $(X, T)$, it is well known that for every $T$-invariant ergodic measure $\mu$, there exists a set $E_\mu$ of $\mu$-measure $1$ s.t. for every "nice" function $f$ 
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^i x)\rightarrow \int f d\mu, \qquad \forall x \in E_\mu.$$
Moreover, for two distinct ergodic measures $\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$, $E_{\mu_1} \cap E_{\mu_2}=\emptyset$.
Therefore, inside the set $E=\bigcup_{\mu \in E(X, T)}E_\mu$, we understand well the behavior of the limit of the ergodic sums.

However, clearly not always $X = E$. Now, my question is: in such a case, where $X \neq E$, what is known about the behavior of the ergodic sums outside of $E$? In other words,  for every $T$-invariant (not necessarily ergodic) measure $\mu$, how (and if and when) can we complete the following equation:

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^i x)\rightarrow \begin{cases}\int f d\nu & x \in E_{\nu} \\ ?& x \not\in E\end{cases} \qquad \text{for }\mu\text{-a.e. } x.$$

Comment: This can be rather wild, think about Bernoulli system, say with the Lebesgue measure, and picking x's which are inside Cantor sets (and not even generic inside such a Cantor set). Moreover, as you ask for $L^{1}$ functions, everywhere question is non-sense, and those "very exceptional" points, must be of $0$-measure wrt any ergodic part (BTW your last equation need to be stated as conditional expectation, as it is in the pointwise ergodic theorem, in this view, you understand better how to phrase your question).

Comment: Yes, you are right. After giving this question additional thought, I realized that $\nu(E^c)=1$ for every measure $\nu$, thus making this question irrelevant.